# How can I concatenate each individual bit representation in my for loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix

My program is a Base64 converter. My first step to approaching this is to convert each char in the string into byte representation, and string build each representation into one big string.
I have this

```
for (( i=0; i<${#orginalString}; i++ ))
do
    echo ${orginalString:$i:1} | xxd -b | awk '{print $2}'

done
```

I'm just wondering how to concatenate each bit representation into one big one.

Comment: What about just simple: `res+=$(echo "${orginalstring:$i:1}" | xxd -b | awk '{print $2}')` and then your string will be in `$res`.

Comment: thank you, my teachers been pretty bad, I've been trying to teach it to myself. Thank you!

Comment: within awk , instead of `print $2` use `printf $2`. At the end of the loop (after done) just add a simple `echo`